# Write Delta Encoded Parquet Files

Tags: parquet, apache-arrow

I know that Apache Arrow Parquet can read spec compliant Delta encoded files, but can not write them out. I am wondering if there is any commonly used open source C++/Python library that can write out Parquet spec compliant delta encoding.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Rust library with Python bindings called [delta-rs](https://github.com/delta-io/delta-rs) that has a [file writer](https://github.com/delta-io/delta-rs/blob/main/python/deltalake/writer.py) that can take an apache arrow `Table` or `RecordBatch` and write to Delta format. Note that it doesn't support transactions or checkpoints yet.

Seems like a pretty active project though, with recent contributions around Delta optimizations so that's cool.

Note: the Delta writer feature of `delta-rs` is labeled Experimental, so it might not be completely stable.